# Flutter TextField how to use WidgetSpan and editing text as normal?

Tags: flutter

I want have a text like this:

```
<cmd>中译英 | 请讲下列中文翻译为英文: </cmd> this is normal
```

Shows in textfield like this:

[image]

I have implemented the widetSpanEditController like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mqtt/app_variables.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mqtt/helpers/string_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mqtt/helpers/ui_helpers.dart';

class WidgetSpanTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  WidgetSpanTextEditingController({String? text})
      : super.fromValue(text == null
            ? TextEditingValue.empty
            : TextEditingValue(text: text));

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan(
      {required BuildContext context,
      TextStyle? style,
      required bool withComposing}) {
    if (text.contains('$SPLIT_CMD_START') && text.contains('$SPLIT_CMD_END')) {
      TextRange? matchedRange;
      TextRange? matchedRange2;
      matchedRange = null;
      matchedRange2 = null;

      matchedRange = findMatchedRangeCommand(text);
      matchedRange2 = findMatchedRangeCommand(text, trimTag: false);

      if (matchedRange != null && matchedRange2 != null) {
        return TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(text: matchedRange!.textBefore(text)),
            WidgetSpan(
                child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          right: 5.0, top: 2.0, bottom: 2.0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                            color: generateGradientColors(matchedRange2!
                                .textInside(text)
                                .trim()
                                .split(SPLIT_CMD_MID)[0])[0],
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  matchedRange2!
                                      .textInside(text)
                                      .trim()
                                      .split(SPLIT_CMD_MID)[0],
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 5.0,
                                ),
                                InkWell(
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.close,
                                    size: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    // controller!.value = controller!.value
                                    //     .copyWith(
                                    //         text: controller!.text.replaceRange(
                                    //             start!, start! + text.length, ''),
                                    //         selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
                                    //             TextPosition(offset: start!)));
                                    debugPrint('clear controller text');
                                    // clearMatchedText(matchedRange, text);
                                    clear();
                                  },
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {})),
            TextSpan(text: matchedRange!.textAfter(text)),
          ],
          style: style,
        );
      } else {
        return TextSpan(text: text, style: style);
      }
    }
    return TextSpan(text: text, style: style);
  }

  void clearMatchedText(TextRange? range, String text) {
    if (range != null) if (range.start >= 0 && range.end <= text.length) {
      final newValue = TextEditingValue(
        text: text.replaceRange(range.start, range.end, ''),
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: range.start),
      );

      value = newValue;
    }
  }

  // TextRange _findMatchedRange(String text) {
  //   final RegExp matchPattern = RegExp(RegExp.escape('\uffff'));
  //   late TextRange matchedRange;

  //   for (final Match match in matchPattern.allMatches(text)) {
  //     matchedRange = TextRange(start: match.start, end: match.end);
  //   }

  //   return matchedRange;
  // }
}
```

But now, when I set the selection of text edit controller, the cursor always comes to begin.

And when editing, the text input but cursor didn't move.

I want:

1. edit as normal, just like the widget at start;
2. I want delete as normal, treat the widget as a single character.

How to make it?